# SDL pixel has wrong values

Tags: c, format, sdl, pixel

I am trying to create a image processing software.

I get some weird results trying to create an Unsharp Mask effect.

I will attach my code here and I will explain what it does and where the problems are (or at least , where I think they are):

```
void unsharpMask(SDL_Surface* inputSurface,SDL_Surface* outputSurface)
{
  Uint32* pixels = (Uint32*)inputSurface->pixels;
  Uint32* outputPixels=(Uint32*)outputSurface->pixels;
  Uint32* blurredPixels=(Uint32*)blurredSurface->pixels;
  meanBlur(infoSurface,blurredSurface);
  for (int i=0;i<inputSurface->h;i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<inputSurface->w;j++)
        {
            Uint8 rOriginal,gOriginal,bOriginal;
            Uint8 rBlurred,gBlurred,bBlurred;
            Uint32 rMask,gMask,bMask;
            Uint32 rFinal,gFinal,bFinal;
            SDL_GetRGB(blurredPixels[i*blurredSurface->w+j],blurredSurface->format,&rBlurred,&gBlurred,&bBlurred);
            SDL_GetRGB(pixels[i*inputSurface->w+j],inputSurface->format,&rOriginal,&gOriginal,&bOriginal);

            rMask=rOriginal - rBlurred;
            rFinal=rOriginal + rMask;
            if(rFinal>255) rFinal=255;
            if(rFinal<=0) rFinal=0;

            gMask=gOriginal - gBlurred;
            gFinal=gOriginal + gMask;
            if(gFinal>255) gFinal=255;
            if(gFinal<0) gFinal=0;

            bMask=bOriginal - bBlurred;
            bFinal=bOriginal + bMask;
            if(bFinal>255) bFinal=255;
            if(bFinal<0) bFinal=0;


            Uint32 pixel =SDL_MapRGB(outputSurface->format,rFinal,gFinal,bFinal);
            outputPixels[i *outputSurface->w+j]=pixel;
        }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, my function gets 2 arguments: the image source(from which pixel data will be extracted, and a target, where the image will be projected). I blur the original image, then i subtract the RGB value of the blurred image from the source image to get "the mask" and then , i add the mask to the original image and that's it. I added some clamping to make sure everything stays in the correct range and then I draw every pixel resulted on the output surface. All these surfaces have been converted in an SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888 . The output surface is loaded into a texture (also SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888) and rendered on the screen.

The results are pretty good in 90% of the image, I get the effect I want, however , there are some pixels that look weird in some places.

Original:

[image: Original Image_2]

Result:

[image: Result_2]

I tried to fix this in any possible way I knew. I thought is a format problem and played with the pixel bit depth , but I couldn't get to a good result. What i found is that all the values > 255 are negative values and I tried to make them completely white. And it works for the skies ,for example, but if you can see on my examples, the dark values, on the grass are also affected, which makes this not a good solution.

I also get this kind of wrong pixels when I want to add a contrast or do sharpen using kernel convolution, and the values are really bright/dark.
In my opinion there may be a problem with the pixel format, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Is there anyone that had this kind of problem before or knows a potential solution?

Comment: `if(rFinal<=0) rFinal=0;` for an unsigned value?? Those supposedly negative values will be caught by `if(rFinal>255) rFinal=255;` which is not what you want, causing the gross errors you are seeing. Also in `rMask=rOriginal - rBlurred` what if `rOriginal < rBlurred`?

Comment: May be not the problem but: an `unsigned int` can never be `< 0`. Subtracting a bigger `unsigned` from a smaller `unsigned` yields again an `unsigned` (which may be even bigger than both arguments). See this for an explanation: [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: Thank you for answers!
When it comes to the unsigned int values is my fault. I thought I can access the negative values in that way, by limiting the range under 0. However, now I understand that the values I get are like this because of the overflow. Thank you, Scheff!
@WeatherVane That's a good point, but I'm not sure what to do when that happens. I removed the wrong lines and that's the result I get:
https://ibb.co/jiJMJ5
Probably in these areas rOriginal<rBlurred and the overflow happens.

Comment: Used signed for `xMask` and `xFinal`.

Comment: @WeatherVane IT WORKS! thank you a lot!